# javascript regex replace variable

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

How can i replace character with regex, but from variable.
Example:

```
var separator = '-';
text = text.replace(/[-\s]+/g, separator);
```

this will replace **-** trailing character with separator, which i the same in this case.

So, i need to set this **-** character from variable **separator**:

```
var separator = '-';
var regex = '/['+separator+'\s]+/g';
text = text.replace(regex, separator);
```

How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to dynamically generate regular expression:

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
var regex = new RegExp('[' + escapeRegExp(separator) + '\\s]', 'g');
```

`escapeRegExp` comes from [Regular Expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

**NOTE**: You have to escape `\`, and `separator`.

Comment: Also, you might have to escape `separator` itself, e.g. consider `separator = "]"`...